# Ajax page jumping after function

Tags: jquery, ajax, layout

I have a page that shows selected items from a table and those not selected. They are loaded into a div via an ajax call on documentready().

```
$('#tags').load('establishments_get_tags.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>');
```

No problem here. Additionally I have written some code to remove an entry from the table if clicked:

```
function DeleteTag(id,tag)
    {           
        $('#tags').load('establishments_get_tags.php?id='+id+"&action=d&tag="+tag);
    }
```

(the action=d triggers the event in the PHP and then the table results are shown)

Works fine, but the page keeps jumping to the top which I do not want. I want it to stay where it is and just reload the div.

Any help would be really great!

Answer (score 1):

Normally a "return false;" to the "onClick" event works in these situations (If I understood it correctly).

Comment: well I now feel a complete idiot! Of course that worked, but I had put it on the method rather than the click. Thanks a great deal!